# FFmpeg : Overlay GIF Rotation and scale

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I need to add multiple gif files as overlay to video. Overlay works but Rotating each Gif is not working somehow.

command

```
 -y -i video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i if4QEgLEtFRcbUBlnL.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i J1XSaMzkdlqDl89NVf.gif -filter_complex [0:v]scale=iw:ih[outv0];[1:0]scale=320.37463:178.75618,rotate=-42.103333*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(-42.103333*PI/180):oh=roth(-42.103333*PI/180);[outv1];[2:0]scale=305.77087:155.56105,rotate=45.82093*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(45.82093*PI/180):oh=roth(45.82093*PI/180);[outv2];[outv0][outv1]overlay=17:311:shortest=1[outo0];[outo0][outv2]overlay=347:296:shortest=1 -r 25 -preset superfast 1579858065554.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some errant semicolons which should give you an error message:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55f54c7ef8c0] No such filter: ''
```

Try:

```
-y -i video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i if4QEgLEtFRcbUBlnL.gif -ignore_loop 0 -i J1XSaMzkdlqDl89NVf.gif -filter_complex [0:v]scale=iw:ih[outv0];[1:0]scale=320.37463:178.75618,rotate=-42.103333*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(-42.103333*PI/180):oh=roth(-42.103333*PI/180)[outv1];[2:0]scale=305.77087:155.56105,rotate=45.82093*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(45.82093*PI/180):oh=roth(45.82093*PI/180)[outv2];[outv0][outv1]overlay=17:311:shortest=1[outo0];[outo0][outv2]overlay=347:296:shortest=1 -r 25 -preset superfast 1579858065554.mp4
```

Comment: That command works, but while rotating input it moves its axis point by some points.  please help.

Comment: can you please give some example here?

Comment: @RonakMakwana Hi, did you solve the moves axis problem?