# How to rotate two overlay parallel using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to continue rotate two overlay image parallelly depend on the audio length.

I am using below command and it is working fine to create a video and it is rotating the first overlay gif image. but it is not rotating the second `textoverlay.png` file. I want to rotate both image in the same time.

```
ffmpeg -loop,1,-i,background.jpg,-ignore_loop,0,-i,overlay1.gif,-i,textoverlay.png,-i,watermark.png,-i,audio.mp3,-filter_complex,[1]scale=524:524,rotate=0.06*PI*t:c=black@0.0:ow='hypot(iw,ih)':oh=ow[b];[2]scale=406:406,rotate=0.06*PI*t:c=black@0.0:ow='hypot(iw,ih)':oh=ow[pic2];[3]scale=100:50[watermark];[0:v][b]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[over1],[over1][pic2]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[pic3],[pic3][watermark]overlay=(W-120):(H-60),scale=830:830,format=yuv420p,-ss,00:00:00,-to,00:00:08,-c:v,mpeg4,-b:a,3M,-c:a,aac,-b:a,192k,-q:v,1,-shortest,output.mp4
```

I also tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893656/ffmpeg-overlay-gif-rotation-and-scale) But this is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-loop 1` to `textoverlay.png`, and use `;` instead of `,` in your filtergraph when separating distinct filterchains.

```
ffmpeg -loop,1,-i,background.jpg,-ignore_loop,0,-i,overlay1.gif,-loop,1,-i,textoverlay.png,-i,watermark.png,-i,audio.mp3,-filter_complex,[1]scale=524:524,rotate=0.06*PI*t:c=black@0.0:ow='hypot(iw,ih)':oh=ow[b];[2]scale=406:406,rotate=0.06*PI*t:c=black@0.0:ow='hypot(iw,ih)':oh=ow[pic2];[3]scale=100:50[watermark];[0:v][b]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[over1];[over1][pic2]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[pic3];[pic3][watermark]overlay=(W-120):(H-60),scale=830:830,format=yuv420p,-ss,00:00:00,-to,00:00:08,-c:v,mpeg4,-c:a,aac,-b:a,192k,-q:v,1,-shortest,output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)  Every time i did this mistake :( Can i add zoom in and out animation to overlay1.gif while rotating?.

Comment: @PradeepKumar That should be asked as a new question.